# Using streams return null if value is false else return true

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the below code

```
 headers.stream().map(MyHeader::getIsCancelled).iterator(),
```

getIsCancelled returns boolean true/false.

I want to modify the above code to return null if the value is false, else return true. Should I use filter to filter for true value and automatically I will get true or null value?

Answer (score 0):

By using `filter`, you can eliminate the `false` values instead of replacing them by `null`.

If you want to replace the `false` values by `null`, you should still use `map`:

```
headers.stream().map(h -> h.getIsCancelled() ? true : null).iterator()
```

I believe that should work, but if not, you can replace `true` with `Boolean.TRUE`.

Comment: (I had to check the boxing, but yes, `true` works).